# Onclick button event does'nt work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call an event from button in HTML to Javascript function("mySubmit()").
When I am clicking on the button, it seems that I do not enter to JS function, as the alert doesn't appear. Any Idea how to make it works?

```html
@model List<Campaign>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    h1
    {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function mySubmit() {
            alert('submit1');            
        }
    </script>

    <title>Customer details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div dir="rtl">
        <h1>
            details</h1>
        <br />
        <h4>
            Phone: @ViewBag.CLID</h4>
        <p>
            <h4 style="display:inline">
                Phone2:</h4>
            <input id="ReturnCLID" type="text" value="@ViewBag.CLID" />
        </p>
        <p style="display:inline"> 
            Campaign: 
        </p>
        <select id="dropdowncamp">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Model[i].CampaignID.ToString() == ViewBag.CampaignCode)
                {
                    
                    <option value=@Model[i].CampaignID selected>
                        @Model[i].CampaignDescription
                    </option>  
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value=@Model[i].CampaignID>
                        @Model[i].CampaignDescription
                    </option>  
                }             
            }
        </select>
        <h4>
            Date: @ViewBag.DialAtInterval</h4>
    </div>
    <input id="Button1" style="align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
        display: block" type="button" value="GO" onclick="mySubmit()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran your code snippet its working!~

Comment: Same, working fine. Are you blocking popups in your browser?

Comment: It's working fine. Instead of `alert`, try to print message on `console`.

Comment: It's working fine David. Might be a browser issue as Chris said above. Try using a different browser :)

Comment: maybe you disabled js?